# SvelteKit page only returning redirect

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, vite, sveltekit

My SvelteKit page seems to only ever return

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/">
```

When it should return my HTML (which comes from the Svelte component:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Notebook from "svelte-material-icons/Notebook.svelte";

    export const ssr = false;
    export const prerender = false;
</script>

<main>
    <section class="buttons">
        <a href="/something">
            <Notebook size="30"/>
            
        </a>
    </section>
</main>

<style lang="less">
    @import '../../styles/variables.less';
    /* some styles */
</style>
```

)

It works fine on localhost, returning the correct HTML, but not on my production build.

I set up lots of logs around the page, in `handle` in `hooks.server.ts`, `load` in `+layout.server.ts` etc. and none of them are reached when I request that page, although logs in the wrapper Express server are reached correctly. I have also tried directly requesting the page with Postman and same result.

In `+layout.server.ts` I do have

```js
console.log(`User '${ username }' failed to authenticate`);
throw redirect(307, '/');
```

however it shouldn't be reached, and doesn't get reached on localhost, and the status code of the requested page with the redirect is 200 not 307, and I don't ever see the log, so I'm not sure how this could be the cause.

I can only think that SvelteKit is SSR/caching this page, however I have

```js
export const ssr = false;
export const prerender = false;
```

on the page, in `+layout.svelte`, `hooks.server.ts` and `+layout.server.svelte`, so I'm not sure what else I can do?

I'm running the SvelteKit server on CentOS and the dev server on Ubuntu, with:

```json
        "svelte": "^3.55.0",
        "svelte-check": "^2.7.1",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.7",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
```

My `svelte.config.js`:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        prerender: { entries: [] }
    }
};

export default config;
```

Comment: `ssr` and `prerender` should not be exported from the view (`.svelte`) files.

According to the docs `ssr` can be in `page.ts` and `layout.ts`. `prerender` can be in various other places ([see docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender)) but should be `false` by default anyway.